# Best way to delete multiple records in a LINQ query?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

What is the best way to remove multiple records in one go with LINQ?

Comment: The following is more for LINQ to Entities, but it may help: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869209/bulk-deleting-via-linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869209/bulk-deleting-via-linq)

Comment: If you need to do something like `DELETE FROM table WHERE ...` then consider using SQL. LINQ may not be the best tool for this job.

Comment: LINQ doesn't delete, it only queries. Deleting records with a LINQ-based ORM is never done by a LINQ statement. All of the answers so far ignore that. Besides that, the term "in one go" is vague. None of the common LINQ-based ORMs will bulk-delete in one SQL statement. Therefore, IMO there is no "best" way, because "best" should at least be "good". LINQ-based ORMs don't even offer a "good" way to do bulk delete.

Answer (score 32):

To delete records with Linq2Sql

```
CustomerDataContext ctx = new CustomerDataContext("connection string");
var customers = ctx.Customers.Where(c => c.Name == "david");

ctx.Customers.DeleteAllOnSubmit(customers);
ctx.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: This is one of the easiest ways but i would not say is the most efficient. There actually is not any optimization being performed. The generated SQL enumerates all objects that match your query, then manually iterates over them to delete them.

See this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869209/bulk-deleting-via-linq

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<RajrangData.tblRelatedProduct>' to 'RajrangData.tblRelatedProduct'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?

Comment: Surely you can't store multiple `Customer` objects in one `Customer` reference... maybe you want something like:
`List<Customer> customers = ctx.Customers.Where(c => c.Name == "david").ToList();`

Answer (score 7):

Using entity framework 6

```
using (EntitiesContext db = new EntitiesContext(connString))
        {
            // Retrieve all records from database for deletion
            IEnumerable<entity> entityList = db.entity.where(x => x.id == id).toList();

            // Use Remove Range function to delete all records at once
            db.entity.RemoveRange(entityList);

            // Save changes
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is How I solved the problem :

```
try
{
    List<MaterialPartSerialNumber> list = db.MaterialPartSerialNumbers.Where(s => s.PartId == PartId && s.InventoryLocationId == NewInventoryLocationId && s.LocationId == LocationId).ToList();
    db.MaterialPartSerialNumbers.RemoveRange(list);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    string error = ex.Message;
}
```

First, you can find a list of the items you want to delete.

Then, you can use the function `RemoveRange(**list_of_item_to_delete**)` so that it removes each instance in the list present in the database.

According to the MSDN, the method removes a range of elements from the List.

For more information, check it here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y33yd2b5(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: pls explain why it works don't just post code as answer

Comment: It works because we are passing to our Object database a list of objects that belongs to that table, so the function RemoveRange can delete all the objects in that list with 1 line code.

Answer (score 4):

The good old SPROCs.....

You can drag the SPROC to your DBML file and it will generate a rich method in your databasecontext class.

- [How to: Call a Stored Procedure by Using LINQ (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb918119.aspx)
- [LINQ and Stored Procedures](http://blogs.msdn.com/zainnab/archive/2007/10/25/linq-and-stored-procedures.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Removing many records based on single where clause

```
context.EntityModel
            .RemoveAll(r => r.property == "propertyEntered");
```

But you could also Remove records from the database that don't exist in `List<ListOfBadRecords>`

```
context.EntityModel
            .Where(w => w.propertyID == ID).ToList()
            .RemoveAll(r => !ListOfBadRecords.Any(a => a.anyID == r.propertyID ));
```

Edit:

Unsure wich is quicker but you could do the 2nd query with this also

`.RemoveAll(r => !ListOfBadRecords.Select(s=>s.propertyID ).Contains(w.propertyID ))`

Edit2: don't forget `context.SaveChanges();` as i did in the first draft

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used, first create an IENumerable object of the table where are the records to be removed are, then just use RemoveRange, and finally just save changes to database. Let's say you want to remove all products from one specific supplier ID on the Products table, this is how you could do that.

```
IEnumerable<Products> ProductsToRemove= db.Products.Where(x => x.SupplierId== Supplierid);
db.Products.RemoveRange(ProductsToRemove);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe its litle late for this answer but today I ran into this demand myself I and I came up with this solution

```
CustomerDataContext ctx = new CustomerDataContext("connection string");

ctx.Customers.DeleteAllOnSubmit(ctx.Customers.Where(c => c.Name == "david"));

ctx.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Surely you can't claim to have 'come up' with that solution when all you did was move the declaration of `cust` from the most popular answer to the `DeleteAllOnSubmit` method.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Khurram, it's much more efficient to do this with a simple stored procedure with LINQ (provided you have sufficient permissions in SQL to do this).  I'll augment this with an example.

The stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[RemovePermissionsFromRole] 
(
    @ROLE_ID int
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DELETE FROM [RolePermissions] WHERE [RoleID] = @ROLE_ID;
END
```

Drag the stored procedure from the database explorer onto the methods pane in your DBML file.  Save the file.  And in code:

```
if (Request.QueryString["RoleID"] != null) {
    int roleID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["RoleID"]);

    SETSDataContext context = new SETSDataContext();
    context.RemovePermissionsFromRole(roleID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With just Entity Framework I found this to be the tightest code.

```
db.PreperProperties.RemoveRange(db.PreperProperties.Where(c => c.preperFk == prpr.id));
db.SaveChanges();
```