# Can we delete multiple records in single query in linq to entity?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to delete multiple records in single linq query. I find the way but its using foreach loop to delete. I want the way like sql delete all the records in single query.

Comment: DbSet.RemoveRange ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.removerange(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Possible duplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519866/how-do-i-delete-multiple-rows-in-entity-framework-without-foreach

Comment: have you seen this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/870216/best-way-to-delete-multiple-records-in-a-linq-query

Answer (score -2):

Below link may help you, please have a look at it

obj.tblA.Where(x => x.fid == i).ToList().ForEach(obj.tblA.DeleteObject);
obj.SaveChanges();

[How to Delete multiple records in Linq to Entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20452652/how-to-delete-multiple-records-in-linq-to-entity)

Regards,
Meet