# Delete query with Where in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

```
DELETE From Table
WHERE ID in (1,2,3, ... )
```

Is there any way to produce following query in `LINQ`? I tried `RemoveRange`, but from `SQL Server Profiler` find that it actually deletes records separately

Comment: have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/q/870216/6400526

Comment: You can search the records using `Contains()` against an array/collection, then delete them using `RemoveRange()` or `DeleteOnSubmit()`.

Comment: RemoveRange doesn't produce following query and there is no DeleteOnSubmit extension method in System.Linq @TetsuyaYamamoto

Answer (score 1):

You could first define the item(s) to remove, then iterate over the list removing them one by one: (note that the whole operation has to be done inside database context scope otherwise it won't work)

```
var toRemove = list.Where(l => l.id == 1 || l.id == 2 || l.id == 3);
foreach (var item in toRemove)
{
    databasecontext.table.Remove(item);      //replace databasecontext.table with your own context and table name
}
```

Comment: This doesn't generate one update statement as explicitly asked in the question.

Answer (score -1):

You can write it in single line

```
table.RemoveAll(tbl => tbl.id == 1 || tbl.id == 2 || tbl.id == 3);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The answer isn't clear. What kind of method is `RemoveAll`?

Answer (score -1):

Try this piece of code to make this, It will work for you.

```
DataContextClass _DbContext = new DataContextClass();
var remove = _DbContext.tableName.where(x=>x.id >= 1 && x.id <= endValue);
if(remove != null)
{
     db.logins.RemoveRange(remove);
     db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. This also "actually deletes records separately".

Comment: @GertArnold it's working on my side.

Comment: Then this is not Entity Framework (or LINQ-to-SQL, as in the question) but another ORM you didn't mention. The point here is how to prevent multiple delete statements like `DELETE xx WHERE Id = yy` even when they occur by one SaveChanges call.