# Update operation in ADO Entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, ado

How do I do the Update table operation in ADO entity framweork ?

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework is currently limited to updates / deletes like this (in pseudo code):

```
DELETE FROM [Table] WHERE Key = Value
```

And you can't do things like this:

```
DELETE FROM [Table] WHERE [RANDOM CLAUSE]
```

The second example is what is generally called DML or Data Modification Language, and it isn't actually supported in EF.

There are workarounds however, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869209/bulk-deleting-in-linq-to-entities/870081) & my answer for more information.

Hope this helps
Alex