# Can EF4 support batch updates?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Does Entity Framework v4 support batch updates/inserts so rather than sending >1 command to a db, it can send >1 command to the DB in one go?

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

I don't believe that has changed.  You have the options of:

- Stored Procedures
- [Stuff like this article](http://geeks.ms/blogs/unai/archive/2008/07/17/multiple-entity-updates-with-entity-framework-ef-fetch-updates.aspx)
- Using T-Sql like [in the answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781175/entity-framework-4-multiple-object-deleteremoveall)

Comment: I think the first or last option is probably the way to go (the second isn't really a batch) but note that the last option is TSQL, not ESQL.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered a good answer to this question here:
[Paul Welter shows how to use EntityFramework.Extended](http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2011/11/29/entity-framework-batch-update-and-future-queries.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that can be accomplished by adding multiple Entity to the context and calling save changes.

```
context.ApplyChanges<T>("Order", obj1);
context.ApplyChanges<T>("Order", obj2);
context.SaveChanges();
```