# Is there a better way to formulate this entity framework 4 update?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have the following code:

```
List<Item> csItems = (from i in context.Items
                      where i.CSItem == true
                      select i).ToList<Item>();
csItems.ForEach(i => i.Active = false);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Seems like this is horribly inefficient as I have to read the entire table in first, then update the tables.  Is there a better way to do this so that I am only doing an update without reading everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to build the `List<T>` of the items.  I, personally, would just enumerate the results and set the values:

```
IQueryable<Item> csItems = (from i in context.Items
                  where i.CSItem == true
                  select i);
foreach(var item in csItems)
     item.Active = false;

context.SaveChanges();
```

Note that there is no bulk-update functionality built-in with Entity Framework, so doing something more efficient would require [some other technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2720660/65358).

Answer (score 2):

Linq2EF doesn't have a built-in bulk update, but you can use [Alex James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/94610/alex-james), [articles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2007/12/07/rolling-your-own-sql-update-on-top-of-the-entity-framework-part-1.aspx) to do it yourself, actually you should implement it yourself. Also simple way is using stored procedures. But if you want to have it yourself you can read all of 4 article series, they are easy to read.