# Entities Framework 4 doing a bulk delete

Tags: entity-framework

I wish to know if there is a good way to do a bulk delete or delete multiple rows using the Entities Framework 4. I can't seam to find a DeleteAll command. The only one that is available is DeleteObject() which only takes one entity, I would like to perform a delete on a list of entities.Is there a better way than to loop trough the list? I did see an article that used ExecuteStoreQuery and created some sql that would perform the delete. Is there a better way than to perform any of these two options   Please advice what is the best way to perform this action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't an elegant way to do this as of yet.  You're correct, you'll have to loop through the list.

This SO post has some good discussions on the topic:
[How do I delete multiple rows in Entity Framework (without foreach)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519866/how-do-i-delete-multiple-rows-in-entity-framework-without-foreach)

Answer (score -2):

I know this post is kinda of old, but a code example would be the following:

`foreach(var item in items)
{
   context.Remove(item);
}`

Comment: Yes you say that, but using pure Entity Framework, it is the way that it has to be done unless you push an actual query to the DB.

Comment: Yeah, but if you would've read the question you would've seen: "Is there a better way than to loop trough the list?"