# Find all IDs in a database which are not in a list of complex objects using Entity Frameworks

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So what I'm trying to do is create a basic sync system between a CSV and a Database (not using SSIS), it also does some other magic stuff for computations and such like.

The first step of a sync is to remove any users in the DB who are no longer in the CSV file.

I have a `List<StaffInfo>` where `StaffInfo` is

```
public class StaffInfo
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Firstname {get;set;
    // etc etc etc ... ... ...
}
```

My initial thoughts was to get a list of UserIDs from the list then select users not in the DB and then loop through and delete, but this seems very wasteful

```
// oUsers contains List<StaffInfo>
// Context is the reference to the EF Context 
var myList = (from c in oUsers select c.ID).ToList();
var usersNotInDb = context.Users.Where(x => !myList.Contains(x.UserId));

foreach (var user in usersNotInDb)
{
    context.DeleteObject(user);
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this without so much either data transfer or manipulation of data directly (i.e converting the complex object to a list of user ids)

Comment: If performance is your concern, you could call a stored procedure and pass list of id's (and so don't use EF).(http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/29792-Pass-array-stored-procedure.aspx) Stored procedure then contains the data logic to delete correct rows.

Comment: I thought about that at first L-Three but if I have a large number of users I'm worried that I may overrun the varchar(MAX)

Comment: Well then you could split it into batches.

Comment: I might end up doing that (assuming I can still manage to get full transaction support working across multiple SPs) but I'm still curious to see if there’s a better solution for EF.

Comment: Check this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069311/passing-an-array-of-parameters-to-a-stored-procedure

Comment: Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588885/entities-framework-4-doing-a-bulk-delete