# DbArithmeticExpression arguments must have a numeric common type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

```
TimeSpan time24 = new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0);
TimeSpan time18 = new TimeSpan(18, 0, 0);    

// first get today's sleeping hours
List<Model.Sleep> sleeps = context.Sleeps.Where(
    o => (clientDateTime - o.ClientDateTimeStamp < time24) && 
          o.ClientDateTimeStamp.TimeOfDay > time18 && 
          clientDateTime.TimeOfDay < time18 && 
          o.UserID == userid).ToList();
```

This Linq expression throws this exception:

```
DbArithmeticExpression arguments must have a numeric common type.
```

Please Help!

Comment: What is the results of `clientDateTime - o.ClientDateTimeStamp`?

Comment: noramlly that should be an object of the TimeSpan, in EF exception is thrown.

Answer (score 279, accepted):

Arithmetic with `DateTime` is not supported in Entity Framework 6 and earlier. You have to use [DbFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.aspx)*. So, for the first part of your statement, something like:

```
var sleeps = context.Sleeps(o =>
    DbFunctions.DiffHours(o.ClientDateTimeStamp, clientDateTime) < 24);
```

Note that the [`DiffHours`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220096.aspx) method accepts `Nullable<DateTime>`.

**Entity Framwork core** (when used with Sql Server, maybe other db providers) supports the DateTime `AddXxx` functions (like `AddHours`). They're translated into `DATEADD` in SQL.

<sub>*[`EntityFunctions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.aspx) prior to Entity Framework version 6.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is an old question but in your specific case instead of using `DBFunctions` as suggested by @GertArnold , couldn't you just invert the operation move out the arithmetic in question from the Lambda?

After all `clientDateTime` and `time24` are fix values so their difference does not need to be recalculated in every iteration.

Like:

```
TimeSpan time24 = new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0);
TimeSpan time18 = new TimeSpan(18, 0, 0);    

var clientdtminus24 = clientDateTime - time24;

// first get today's sleeping hours
List<Model.Sleep> sleeps = context.Sleeps.Where(
    o => (clientdtminus24 < o.ClientDateTimeStamp) && 
          o.ClientDateTimeStamp.TimeOfDay > time18 && 
          clientDateTime.TimeOfDay < time18 && 
          o.UserID == userid).ToList();
```

This refactor is usually possible if you are trying to compare the stored datetime shifted by a fix timestamp with an other datetime.

Comment: I had this exact situation, and this helped. However, the scope of this solution is very limited to a specific kind of problem.

Comment: @Zimano It solves OPs problem without requiring him to change technologies or resort to hacks. If it can be refactored like this then do it, if not then do it like in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

The other way, if performance is not the true goal, you can try using `AsEnumerable()`.
So, it would be like

```
List<Model.Sleep> sleeps = context.Sleeps.AsEnumerable().Where(....
```

Adding AsEnumerable() will convert the SQL query to entity and allows to run .Net functions on them. For more info, check here [about AsEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435(v=vs.110).aspx)