# Debug error message please. DbArithmeticExpression Arguements must have a numeric common type

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to delete all items which are older than 3 hours in a table, but get the following error...

DbArithmeticExpression arguments must have a numeric common type.

```
// Method to clean items in baskets table which are over 3 hours old.
public void CleanBasket()
{
    var expired = (from a in db.Baskets
                   where (DateTime.Now - a.DateCreated).TotalHours > 3  select a);
    foreach (Basket basket in expired) db.DeleteObject(expired);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I have never seen this error before, can anybody help me to debug please?

FYI, I have also tried...
    var expired = (from a in db.Baskets where (DateTime.Now.Subtract(a.DateCreated).Hours > 3) select a);

but I get the error message "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.TimeSpan Subtract(System.DateTime)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Answer (score 2):

EF doesn't support `DateTime - DateTime`.

Comment: I've tried changing 3 to 3d and also to 3.0 and both give me the same error message

Comment: I get the same error when trying where (DateTime.Now - a.DateCreated).TotalHours > 3d  select a);

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.DiffHours](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) as per this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9860858/345659

```
var expired = (from a in db.Baskets
               where DbFunctions.DiffHours(DateTime.Now, a.DateCreated) > 3
               select a);
```