# SQL Time Duration Between Records

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have the following table:

```
CamId   RegNumber   DateSeen
5   G1234B  18/02/2014 11:54
3   G1234B  18/02/2014 11:51
5   G11854  18/02/2014 11:50
3   G11854  18/02/2014 11:49
3   G24581  18/02/2014 11:48
```

I need to know the time taken from when a registration number is seen at CamId 3 to CamId 5, a reg number must exist in both CamId 3 and 5 for this to work.

The result i am looking for is a list of registration numbers together with a time difference in seconds (for the purpose of this demo in minutes):

```
RegNumber   Duration
G1234B             3
G11854             1
```

I then want to add up all these durations and get the median or average value.

Hopefully someone can assist, a linq sql statement would be ideal.

Comment: Is the combination of `CamId` and `RegNumber` unique?

Comment: yes it would have to match on the same regnumber and the date of camid  3 must be less to that of camid5

Comment: there can also be other entries but it must get the last two available for a reg number. e.g. there might be 10 entries on cam id 5 and 10 entries on cam id 3 but it should use the latest values only

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Enumerable.GroupBy`, then select the latest record with `CamId == 5`, subtract it with the earliest record with `CamId == 3` and use `TimeSpan.TotalSeconds`.

```
var query = db.Registration
    .GroupBy(r => r.RegNumber)
    .Select(grp => new 
    {
        RegNumber = grp.Key,
        Duration = (grp.Where(r => r.CamId == 5)
                      .OrderByDescending(r => DateSeen)
                      .Select(r => r.DateSeen)
                      .FirstOrDefault()  
                  - grp.Where(r => r.CamId == 3)
                      .OrderBy(r => DateSeen)
                      .Select(r => r.DateSeen)
                      .FirstOrDefault()).TotalSeconds
    });
```

**Update**: *"Would you be able to provide the above in an SQL statement?"*

```
WITH CTE AS
(
     SELECT [CamId], [RegNumber], [DateSeen],
       Duration = DATEDIFF(second, 
                          (SELECT MIN(DateSeen)FROM dbo.Registration r2
                           WHERE r1.RegNumber=r2.RegNumber
                           AND   r2.CamId = 3),
                          (SELECT MAX(DateSeen)FROM dbo.Registration r2
                           WHERE r1.RegNumber=r2.RegNumber
                           AND   r2.CamId = 5)),
       RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RegNumber ORDER BY DateSeen)
     FROM dbo.Registration r1
)
SELECT [RegNumber], [Duration]
FROM CTE 
WHERE [Duration] IS NOT NULL AND RN = 1
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7204e/4/0)</kbd>

Comment: @Tommy: There is no `Where` on the main query so it will return all records grouped by `RegNumber`. What does `query.ToList().Count` return?

Comment: returns an error "ArgumentException was unhandled" DbArithmeticExpression arguments must have a numeric common type.

Comment: @Tommy: you haven't mentioned entity framework, have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820401/dbarithmeticexpression-arguments-must-have-a-numeric-common-type

Comment: Would you be able to provide the above in an SQL statement?

Comment: @Tommy: edited my answer. Change `DATEDIFF(second ...` to `DATEDIFF(minute ...` if you want to see the minutes instead.