# Compare DateTime in Sqlite with Entity and Linq

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, datetime, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to run the following:

```
backupEvents = backupEvents.Where(e => e.Timestamp >= DateTime.Now - new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0, 0));
```

But this gives me an error saying

> "DbArithmeticExpression arguments must have a numeric common type".

Searching StackOverflow, I find that [Arithmetic with DateTime is not supported in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9860858/6296435).

So I tried:

```
backupEvents = backupEvents.Where(o => DbFunctions.DiffHours(o.Timestamp, DateTime.Now) <= 1);
```

But I also can't use the DbFunctions offered as a solution, because I'm using SQLite, and it doesn't have them, and I get an error saying: "no such function: DiffHours"

So - is there a way to compare dates in SQLite, using entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way - this works:

```
DateTime offsetHour = DateTime.Now.Add(new TimeSpan(-1, 0, 0));
backupEvents = backupEvents.Where(e => e.Timestamp >= offsetHour);
```