# how can I pass an array to a execute store command?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

How to pass an array of integer separated by comma to an `ExecuteStoreCommand`in the entities 
as a parameter
I am not able to execute this :

```
this.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand("INSERT INTO SurveyPatientListMrns 
  (UserData, MrnId) SELECT DISTINCT '{0}' , MrnId 
FROM PatientVisits WHERE (FacilityId = {1})
AND (UnitId IN ({2}))", userData, facilityId, (string.Join(",", unitIds)));
```

Here `(string.Join(",", unitIds))` is a string and i can not cast it as integer because of the commas. How can i pass the parameter then?

FYI, unitIds is a array of integers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though it looks like a `string.Format` operation, `ExecuteStoreCommand` is internally building a parameterized query to increase performance and help protect you from SQL injection attacks. [(MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.executestorecommand.aspx)

When you do your `string.Join` as a parameter to `ExecuteStoreCommand`, it treats that result not as a list of values for the `IN` clause,  but a string that just happens to look like one. Basically it will generate an `IN` clause that looks like this:

```
(UnitId IN ('1,2,3'))
```

Which is obviously not what you want.

You're going to have to build the SQL command with the `string.Join`-ed list of `uinitIds` BEFORE passing it `ExecuteStoreCommand`:

```
string query = @"INSERT INTO SurveyPatientListMrns  (UserData, MrnId) 
    SELECT DISTINCT '{0}' , MrnId 
    FROM PatientVisits WHERE (FacilityId = {1}) AND 
    (UnitId IN (" + string.Join(",", unitIds) + "))";
this.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand(query, userData, facilityId);
```

Normally one should avoid dynamically building SQL queries because of the possibility of a SQL injection attack, but in this case, you know that `unitIds` is a list of integers, and therefore you should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Same approach as the answer, just demonstrating using strongly typed result set.

```
void Main()
{
    int[] operationIds = { 1000, 1001 };
    var result = ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<EncyptedPatientInfoDataContract>(
                        $@"SELECT OperationId, Name, OfficialId, IsPatientEncrypted FROM Patient WHERE OperationId IN ({string.Join(",", operationIds)})");
                        result.Dump();
}
```

Dump method is a method in Linqpad. Screenshot of working sample in Linqpad 5:

[image]

As the accepted answer said:

- Build a query string against the store where you build up the IN clause
  using for example string.Join to build up the comma separated array of string values

  - When using ExecuteStoreQuery you can in case you use a SELECT project the data into a strongly typed entity of your choice - as long as its properties and respective property types match up with database contents such that Entity Framework can successfully materialize the contents into the POCO object you use as a generic argument.