# Pass a DateTime[] as a SQL parameter for ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, objectcontext

I'm using [ExecuteStoreCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.executestorecommand.aspx) to facilitate bulk deletes.

#### This Works

```
// ExecuteStoreCommand syntax via http://stackoverflow.com/a/13024320/740639
// Delete all of today's events
DateTime eventDate = DateTime.Now;

string sql = "DELETE FROM EventCalendar WHERE EventDate = {0}";
context.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand(sql, new object[] { eventDate });
```

#### I want to do this, but it does not work

I get an ArgumentException: "No mapping exists from object type System.DateTime[] to a known managed provider native type."

```
// Delete all of the events for the past 3 days
DateTime[] eventDates = new DateTime[] {
   DateTime.Now.AddDay(-1),
   DateTime.Now.AddDay(-2),
   DateTime.Now.AddDay(-3)
};

string sql = "DELETE FROM EventCalendar WHERE EventDate IN ({0})";
context.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand(sql, new object[] { eventDates });
```

#### Proposed Solution

I could convert my DateTime[] into the string "'2013-06-24', '2013-06-23', '2013-06-22'" and pass that as the parameter, but that seems like a hack.

I know there are libraries that add bulk delete support to EF, but I don't want to go that route at this time.

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible solution, but doesn't make me happy http://stackoverflow.com/a/13169633/740639

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you manipulate the string, every time you change the dates you will get a slightly different SQL statement.  It may look the same, but the string is different and will have a different hash.  So this subverts caching of the execution plan and kills performance.

You can't really pass parameters in an `IN` clause the way you're thinking.  There are some other ideas [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/337704/634824) that might work, but if you read the notes they all say they have lousy performance.

If you can be assured that you will have a fixed number of inputs, you could use the technique of passing them as separate parameters:

```
... WHERE EventDate IN (@dt1, @dt2, @dt3)
```

Otherwise, I would go with an approach like Tom suggested, pass them as a delimited string and parse it on the server.

Also - since you are doing an exact match, you probably want to snap to midnight using `DateTime.Today` rather than `DateTime.Now`, or use the `.Date` property of an existing DateTime.

Here's another suggestion, if you really are just trying to delete for the last three days, why not do this?

```
string sql = "DELETE FROM EventCalendar WHERE EventDate BETWEEN {0} AND {1}";
context.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand(sql,
    new object[] { DateTime.Today.AddDays(-3), DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1) });
```

Or with a bit of thought, you could probably just use sql `getdate()` and similar functions instead of passing parameters at all.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I went with your `BETWEEN` solution. You were right, the "last 3 days" was just for the purpose of writing a code sample, I really just wanted to delete over a date range.

Answer (score 1):

You could combine the dates with a delimiter on the .net side, pass it through as a paramter, and then use a Table-Valued function to split a delimited string on the server side.

Pass in something like "2013-06-24|2013-06-23|2013-06-22"

http://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/split-string-to-table-using-transact-sql/