# Deleting a collection in an entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a entity that has a collection of entities and I wish to delete that collection. The 
collection is 15K or so and it takes a long time to do a normal delete.

```
Page objPage = context.Pages.Where(p => p.PageID == "27486451851").First();
objPage.UserPosts.ForEach(x => { context.Posts.Remove(x); });
```

How can I get better performance on this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519866/how-do-i-delete-multiple-rows-in-entity-framework-without-foreach

Answer (score 1):

Use:

`context.ExecuteStoreCommand("DELETE FROM [UsersPosts] WHERE PageID = @0", 27486451851);`

Answer (score 1):

I've observed significant performance degradation while adding and removing a large number of entities with `DbContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true`.  For some strange reason, EF calls `DbContext.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()` under the hood each time you call `DbSet<T>.Add()` or `DbSet<T>.Remove()`.  This causes the ChangeTracker to iterate through every entity in the entire collection looking for changes with each addition/removal.  This seems completely unnecessary.

A possible solution is the following, which puts off change detection until you have removed all of your Post entities, thereby calling `context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()` only once.

```
context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
Page objPage = context.Pages.Where(p => p.PageID == "27486451851").First();
objPage.UserPosts.ForEach(x => { context.Posts.Remove(x); });
context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
context.SaveChanges();
context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
```

Comment: I would be careful to judge the authors of the EF to quickly about "unnecessary change checks." The Entity being removed could itself have a two sided Navigation Property. That said, the automatic Detect changes makes Add en Remove operations indeed very slow.

Answer (score -1):

```
using (var context = new DatabaseEntities())
{
    context.ExecuteStoreCommand("DELETE FROM Pages WHERE PageID == {0}", "27486451851");
}
```