# Delete SQL IN way using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to delete multiple rows in EF5.

closer i found is 
[How do I delete multiple rows in Entity Framework (without foreach)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519866/how-do-i-delete-multiple-rows-in-entity-framework-without-foreach)

Am struck on how to proceed on this as i need to use LINQ(SQL IN)Version and i dont want to execute SQL.

I have a List of `ID's` and i need to pass it to IN. How do i implement in `LINQ to Entities(EF)`

SQL Version of what am tryin to do:

```
DELETE FROM TEST WHERE TESTID IN (2,3,4,5)
```

and i need to pass IN parameters from `LIST<ID>`.

What is the best way to implement this in EF?

Thanks

Comment: So http://stackoverflow.com/a/13903501/212121 and using `Contains` does not help?

Comment: It does! but i thoought ll get better way fr my scenario with passing LIST<id> and posted hre !

Comment: This is not a task for LINQ! LINQ is a query language for data selection not for executing commands!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use a loop. Your problem is just a cosmetic one, because after using:

```
var foo =
    from item in db.Test
    where idlist.Contains(item.TESTID)
    select item;

foreach (var item in foo)
{
    db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Deleted;
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

the EF will create someting like

```
DELETE FROM TEST WHERE TESTID IN (2,3,4,5)
```

for you.

Comment: The DeleteObject method from entity also can be used.
db.DeleteObject(item);