# EF: Delete many

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

In a daily import procedure processed in an MVC application, I need to delete all entities that have a datestamp in a fixed timehorizon before doing the actual import. Is there a way to bring this code..

```
var deleteShows = db.Shows.Where(x => x.begin >= DateTime.Today.Date).ToList();
foreach (Show show in deleteShows)
    {
        db.Shows.Remove(show);
    }
db.SaveChanges();
```

.. into a shorter / quicker version, something like

```
db.Shows.Where(x => x.begin >= DateTime.Today.Date).ToList().ForEach(db.Shows.Remove(???));
```

Comment: https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/wiki/Batch-Update-and-Delete

Comment: Although not a duplicate, this question has an overview of all mass-delete options available in EF: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519866/how-do-i-delete-multiple-rows-in-entity-framework-without-foreach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah indeed:

```
db.Shows.Where(x => x.Date >= DateTime.Today.Date)
    .ToList().ForEach( s => db.Shows.Remove(s));
```

Comment: Thank you, that works and looks much better :o) one correction (my fault): in the Where-part, delete ".Date" from x-selection: db.Shows.Where(x => x.begin >= DateTime.Today.Date)
    .ToList().ForEach( s => db.Shows.Remove(s));

Comment: Isn't `s => db.Shows.Remove(s)` redundant and can simply be `db.Shows.Remove`?

Comment: @ta.speot.is - I don't think so. Because the `.Remove(T entity)` gets an entity object and hasn't any overload for taking no arguments...

Comment: @AminSaghi ta.speot.is was talking about a method-group

Comment: @Grumbler85 - I don't know about that. What is method-group?

Comment: To continue @Grumbler85's comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2914951/242520 is the best example