# How to Delete multiple records in Linq to Entity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, entity-framework

I have a tblA in sql:

```
id  int  (primary key)
fid  int
```

data in tblA is:

```
1   1
2   1
3   2
4   2
5   3
6   3
```

i delete **one record** by following code:

```
DatabaseEntities obj = new DatabaseEntities();
int i = 2;
tblA t = obj.tblA.Where(x => x.fid == i).FirstOrDefault();
obj.DeleteObject(t);
obj.SaveChanges();
```

i delete multiple records by following code:

```
DatabaseEntities obj = new DatabaseEntities();
int i = 2;
while (obj.tblA.Where(x => x.fid == i).Count() != 0)
{
   tblA t = obj.tblA.Where(x => x.fid == i).FirstOrDefault();
   obj.DeleteObject(t);
   obj.SaveChanges();
}
```

Is there any solution for delete **multiple records** in linq to entity?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do the following, which is technically still a loop.

```
obj.tblA.Where(x => x.fid == i).ToList().ForEach(obj.tblA.DeleteObject);
obj.SaveChanges();
```

The alternative is calling the SQL directly.

Comment: I am not able to find DeleteObject :(

Answer (score 2):

There is a extension provided at [EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended)

to delete all object

```
//delete all users where FirstName matches
context.Users.Delete(u => u.FirstName == "firstname");
```

---

Additionally look into : [How do I delete multiple rows in Entity Framework (without foreach)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519866/how-do-i-delete-multiple-rows-in-entity-framework-without-foreach)

Comment: Is the `Delete` method been added in EF 5 or 6? Didn't know it yet

Comment: @Serv = its a extension for for entityframework!

Comment: @SamieyMehdi - i am using it myself, can i ask which version of ef ur using ?

Comment: Extension method working well for me.