# Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.EntityContainerMapping'

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, dbcontext, entity-framework-extended

When I debug the following code, I receive the message "`System.TypeLoadException` was caught" when I perform the `Delete()`.

```
Using db As New ScholarshipEntities

    db.ApplicationHistories.Where(Function(h) h.HistoryTypeId = 0).Delete()
    db.SaveChanges()

End Using
```

I am using EF 6.1 in Visual Studio 2013. I also have the EntityFramework.Extended library installed.

I have no trouble querying results. I thought the bug might occur when the `Where` method has no results, but that is not the case. I also have no problem adding new models (.edmx), which was a problem some people with this exception had.

I just recently upgraded to EF 6.1 and installed the Extended library. This is my first time using one of the extended methods. I've un-installed and re-installed the nuget packages with no success.

IntelliTrace shows the following exceptions from the `Delete()` call (in order):

- `'EntityFramework.Reflection.DynamicProxy' does not contain a definition for 'InternalQuery'`
- `Cannot implicitly convert type 'EntityFramework.Reflection.DynamicProxy' to 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery<Scholarship.ApplicationHistory>'`
- `Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.EntityContainerMapping'`

I've [added an issue](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/issues/97) on the Extended library's github.

**Update**
I've reinstalled EF and the EF.Extended library with no luck. I am able to use `RemoveRange` in its place. I am able to create a new project, install the packages, add a model mapped to the same database, and successfully use `Delete`. Obviously, the problem is in my current solution.

In my solution, I have an ASP.NET project and a regular library project. In the ASP project, a page's code behind calls a method in the library `RemoveHistory`. The library contains classes for the business logic and data access.  Both classes implement interfaces. The actual `Delete` occurs in the data access class. My model also resides in this library project.

I may be able to create a completely new project and bring everything over, but that will take quite some time. Even if I did, **I want to understand why it doesn't work in the first place**, so that I don't have to repeat this process.

Comment: Never used it, and not sure this is related, but based on [the documentation](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended) for `EntityFramework.Extended`, shouldn't your delete be `db.ApplicationHistories.Delete(Function(h) h.HistoryTypeId = 0)`?  I would guess that the `db.SaveChanges()` call is also unnecessary if it's deleting without bringing the entity into the context.

Comment: You may be correct about the `db.SaveChanges()` (I won't know until the `Delete` works). The delete method you wrote is obsolete after the API was refactored. The current documentation says to use `query.Where(expression).Delete()` syntax instead. That said, using the obsolete syntax throws the same exception. Thanks for your comment, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "solved" the issue some time ago. I'll eventually go back to try and reproduce the problem to confirm my suspicions.

There were multiple versions of Entity Framework installed in the solution. This didn't appear to affect basic EF functionality, though I'm sure it did in some subtle, potentially buggy fashion.

Every time the solution was opened, NuGet would state that it couldn't complete uninstallation. Uninstalling and restoring via NuGet was unsuccessful, and the packages had to be deleted manually. Once completely removed, I installed the packages again. This resolved the issue.

I wish I could give a more technical answer, though the basic reason was forgetting to look closer at the packages folder and configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete certain rows do it like that:

```
Using db As New ScholarshipEntities

  db.ApplicationHistories.RemoveRange(db.ApplicationHistories.Where(Function(h) h.HistoryTypeId = 0))
  db.SaveChanges()

End Using
```

If you want to remove single entity do it like that:

```
Using db As New ScholarshipEntities

  db.ApplicationHistories.Remove(db.ApplicationHistories.Single(Function(h) h.HistoryTypeId = 0))
  db.SaveChanges()

End Using
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of `RemoveRange` in EF6. However, I'm trying to avoid querying the database, loading it all into memory, then deleting the objects one at a time, as `RemoveRange` does). That is the problem [this person had](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22157005/bulk-deleting-rows-with-removerange). What I'm trying to figure out is if there's some bug I've encountered in EF.Extended, or if my setup is wrong somewhere. For the time being, I've had to settle for deleting objects one at a time (not using EF.Extended), but I'd like to take advantage of the library and its promised benefits.

Comment: Where from comes this Delete method, you are using? I haven't found such method among linq set.

Comment: [EntityFramework.Extended library](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended) - my question is tagged with it and I link to an issue I opened on the project's GitHub page.

Comment: I've tried your code and it works perfectly fine. Are you using the most up to date version of EF.Extended?

Comment: I am. I have also added an update to my question for more context. I'm positive the issue is with my solution, but it's only manifesting in this bug.

Comment: I appreciate your interest, although your post doesn't actually answer my question. If I don't receive a response today, then the bounty will go to you. However, I cannot accept this as the answer, and I'd like you to make it clear that your answer uses the standard Entity Framework as an alternative to the EF.Extended library that I'm trying to use. Thanks again.

Comment: I really want to help you but on my application Delete method from EF.Extended worked perfectly. To try to fix this I need to first see this error in my application. I would need some more data - a model details maybe. Maybe you could try to prepare simple application that uses this and compare it your code which causes exception and this will give you information what so special you've got in the code that makes it not working. Then I will gladly investigate that further.