# Brute force collection in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, linq

Good day to all!

There is such a code

```
var userRoles = context.UserRoles.Where(ur => ur.UserId == id);                    
if (userRoles.Any())
{
    context.UserRoles.RemoveRange(userRoles);
}
var userCars  = context.UserCars.Where(uc => uc.UserId == id);
```

It is necessary to get rid of the extra SELECT code before deleting:

```
context.UserRoles.RemoveRange (userRoles);
```

How to do it better?

If RemoveRange loops through the incoming collection, then for each record in the UserCars collection, a separate query will be executed into the database, which is bad. The sample should be within the same request:

```
var userCars = context.UserCars.Where (uc => uc.UserId == id);
```

How to do it better?

Sincerely, Mikhail

Comment: A few options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22157005/bulk-deleting-rows-with-removerange).

Answer (score 0):

if i understand right you want to perform the select and the delete in one query

i think this should help you [Entity Framework Plus
Batch Delete](https://entityframework-plus.net/batch-delete)