# how to remove all records from a table after selection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I can get all the records in a table i need:

```
 using (Entities db = new Entities())
                {
    db.PROJ_PLOFDataRecord.Where(x => x.Account_Id == 1);
}
```

I now want to remove them...cant i say something like .RemoveAll()

Comment: Possible duplicate question for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519866/how-do-i-delete-multiple-rows-in-entity-framework-without-foreach

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are in EF6, try

```
db.PROJ_PLOFDataRecord.Local.Clear();
db.SaveChanges();
```

You may need to call `db.PROJ_PLOFDataRecord.Load()` first to get the Local collection populated.

Here is the documentation for .Local ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696248%28v=vs.113%29.aspx))

Comment: doesnt allow me to say .local

Comment: Is it a DbSet, are you using EF6 (I believe 5 works as well)? I attached the documentation in case it helps you determine what you are missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
yourContext.Database
           .ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE <Table>");
```

Comment: Yeah. If he has an anemic table with eithe no foreign keys or was not smart enough to set up foreign key relationships that may even work. Bad news is that this would in most cases be a sign of incompetence - or a REALLY rare table. With foreign keys that - fails. -1.

Comment: @John, If you have FK why you want to remove all data from table?

Comment: +1 I actually think this is an interesting approach. The FK problem might even be ok if ON DELETE CASCADE was set during creation.