# How to delete multiple records with Entity Framework ASP.Net MVC 5?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have Table like the following image:

[image]

how can I delete all records of table using Entity FrameWork based on ProjectId ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I delete multiple rows in Entity Framework (without foreach)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519866/how-do-i-delete-multiple-rows-in-entity-framework-without-foreach)

Comment: I don't care with foreach or with out foreach I want a good way to delete records based on ProjectId

Answer (score 82, accepted):

This one liner will do it:

```
  db.ProRel.RemoveRange(db.ProRel.Where(c => c.ProjectId == Project_id));
```

Comment: Great and really simple and Perfect answer thanks very much it worked perfect

Comment: No problem I am happy to solved your problem.

Comment: Simple and elegant solution, thanks!

Comment: not all the EF version support `RemoveRange()` if this is the case use Jesse Carter's answer instead

Comment: What @AtulChaudhary said. RemoveRange doesn't take an IQueriable so all it's doing is retrieving to the client all the data you want to delete, and then enumerating it. What's really required is a way of passing to the DB a condition that defines what you want to delete and have that done by the database without pointlessly copying all that data to the client.

Comment: Elegant solution, thanks

Comment: Best one liner so far. Don't for get to add db.SaveChanges();

Answer (score 16):

```
context.Projects.Where(p => p.ProjectId == projectId)
               .ToList().ForEach(p => context.Projects.Remove(p));
context.SaveChanges();
```

Taken from this [very similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519866/how-do-i-delete-multiple-rows-in-entity-framework-without-foreach) (which should probably be marked as duplicate).

Comment: I think you forgot to actually delete.

Comment: @KirkWoll ForEach(context.Projects.DeleteObject); deletes them

Comment: um...no, that's not right.

Comment: Oh, I see, `DeleteObject` lives on `ObjectContext`. (The current and now standard `DbContext` doesn't have that method)

Comment: Exactly It doesn't have DeleteObject Method

Comment: Exactly It doesn't have DeleteObject Method

Comment: Updated to use Remove instead

Comment: The solution I'm working on is in an older version of EF that doesn't support RemoveRange.  I ended up using this as it was the next best solution I found.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `DbSet.RemoveRange()` and pass in an `IEnumerable<Model>`.

You build a list of models with `ProjectId` and pass them in `RemoveRange()` using the data context. Finally, call `SaveChanges()`.

Comment: I am new to ASP.Net MVC and Entity Framework could you give example in detail my Table Name is ProvRel how can I delete multiple records from this table Based on ProjectId

Comment: No problem, I will need to see more code. I need your data context and data model.

Comment: private MYDBContext db = new MYDBContext();

Comment: not all the EF version support `RemoveRange()` if this is the case use Jesse Carter's answer instead