# Deleting multiple records at a time entities framework 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I created a MVC application using entity framework 5. I need to delete data from table using query. I have done one record delete, But now i have requiment to delete multiple records at a time.

```
My Table USER:
Id      Name     cityId
1       Rajesh      1
2       Rahul       1
3       Sulagna     1
4       Rajoshri    2
5       Deb         2
```

Now i need to delete where cityid = 1

Code which i have tried:

```
List<USER> listUser = new List<USER>();
listUser = db.USERs.Where(w => w.cityId == 1).ToList();
db.Entry(listUser).State = System.Data.EntityState.Deleted;
db.SaveChanges();
```

But its giving error.

I have searched and found a RemoveRange method to delete multiple records. But RemoveRange is not availabel in my project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete multiple records with Entity Framework ASP.Net MVC 5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27192920/how-to-delete-multiple-records-with-entity-framework-asp-net-mvc-5)

Comment: @JaiminSoni i ahev tried that.

Comment: i have post ans in this post. try that

Answer (score 1):

For EF5 you need to install EF extended library: [EntityFramework.Extended](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Extended)
after sucessfully installation try this below code.

```
var query = from c in db.USERs
                where c.cityId  == 1            
                select c;
query.Delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach (var user in db.USERs.Where(u => u.cityId == 1).ToList()) { 
    db.USERs.Remove(user):
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

With EF6 it's easier:

```
db.USERs.RemoveRange(db.USERs.Where(u => u.cityId == 1));
db.SaveChanges();
```

Let me know if this helps,

Alberto

Comment: Did you insert required NS?
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;

Comment: I have added still its not available. Have u tried this in entity framework 5?

Comment: Sorry I miss that part... RemoveRange is available in EF6! OK: updated answer!

Answer (score -1):

This would help to `remove` from the DB using `Entity Framework`:

**Code:** `db.USERs.RemoveRange(db.USERs.Where(w => w.cityId == 1));`