# How can I delete rows from tables using EF when inside an Asp.Net method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have this method:

```
[Route("Delete")]
public IHttpActionResult Delete()
{

}
```

What I would like to do is to delete from three tables that are here:

```
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<SampleSentence> SampleSentences { get; set; } 
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Synonym> Synonyms { get; set; } 
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<WordForm> WordForms { get; set; }
```

Is there a delete function in EF6 that I can use to delete all the rows or should I somehow make a SQL call?

Comment: Project the DbSets into a List and then Enumerate each to `DbSet.Remove`. You can then call `SaveChanges` on the `DbContext`. If not you can always Use `DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand`

Comment: @Nkosi - Would that not make many calls to the database? Can I do it with somehow sending SQL direct to the database?

Comment: Yes, the second part of my comment allows for SQL direct on the database

Comment: With the first suggestion it will only execute one call when you invoke SaveChanges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a DbContext derived class...

```
using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope()) {
    try {
        string sql = @"
DELETE SampleSentence 
DELETE Synonym 
DELETE WordForm
";

        int count = myDbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql);
        if(count > 0) 
            transactionScope.Complete();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        //Logging
    }
}
```

Comment: @Nikosi - Does that call to the database return a code to indicate if it worked or not? Just wondering if I should put all this in a try catch to check for possible exceptions. Thanks.

Comment: it's normally the count of how many row were affected by the command. You can wrap it in a transaction and try catch in case of error so you can roll back if needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this [EntityFramework.Extended library](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended), with it help one can write:

```
context.SampleSentences.Delete();
context.Synonyms.Delete();
context.WordForms.Delete();
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found on stackoverflow

```
db.ProRel.RemoveRange(db.ProRel.Where(c => c.ProjectId == Project_id));
```

[How to delete multiple records with Entity Framework ASP.Net MVC 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27192920/how-to-delete-multiple-records-with-entity-framework-asp-net-mvc-5)

But I use this method to delete a row

```
var Cert = (from cert in db.TblCompCertUploads where cert.CertID == ID select cert).FirstOrDefault();
if (Cert != null)
{
    db.TblCompCertUploads.DeleteObject(Cert);
    db.SaveChanges();
    ViewBag.Msg = "Deleted Successfully";
}
```

For Mulitple Rows

```
List<tbl_CompCertificate> tbp = db.tbl_CompCertificate.Where(t => t.CompCer_CompId == CompId).ToList();
foreach (tbl_CompCertificate t in tbp)
{
    db.tbl_CompCertificate.DeleteObject(t);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```