# Delete row from SQL Server database, C#

Tags: c#, database, mdf

I want to Delete Rows from a Database which is stored in a .mdf in a C#-Controller

```
URLDatabaseEntities _db = new URLDatabaseEntities();
_db.
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What `URLDatabaseEntities` do exactly? You mean with ADO.NET way? Can you please be more specific?

Comment: Yes, its ADO.Net Data Model

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delete multiple rows in Entity Framework (without foreach)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519866/how-do-i-delete-multiple-rows-in-entity-framework-without-foreach)

Comment: It is, thank you. Solved it with the other thread :)