# How to create Action to Delete records older than two weeks in Asp.Net Mvc project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a table with name "Loggs" as you see in image. 
[image]

I want to create action that delete all records that is older than two weeks. For example today is 2017-11-20 and LoggId 1 , 2 and 3 have old Loggdate. How to create to delete them?
I tried to put those LoggId's in Array , and I tried even old dates in Array but then I don't know how to do ....

Here is Array of old dates

```
public DateTime[] OldDates()
{
  var oldDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-14);

 return  context.Loggs.Where(u => u.LoggDate < oldDate).Select(d => d.LoggDate).ToArray();

}
```

And tried by Id's too

```
public int[] OldDateId()
{
  var oldDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-14);
  return  context.Loggs.Where(u => u.LoggDate < oldDate).Select(d => d.LoggId).ToArray();

}
```

But then How to create delete action....?
I tried like this but I don't how to complite it

```
public ActionResult DeleteOldLogs()
{
  var datesToRemove = OldDates();
  using (context)
  {
    context.Loggs.Remove(.....) // I don't know how to formulate here ..;)
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delete multiple rows in Entity Framework (without foreach)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519866/how-do-i-delete-multiple-rows-in-entity-framework-without-foreach)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume Loggs is a table and you're asking how to use Entity to delete something?

```
var oldDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-14);
var dates = context.Loggs.Where(l => l.LoggDate < oldDate);
context.Loggs.RemoveRange(dates);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `RemoveRange` method which accepts a collection of your entities.

Also your action method needs to return something.

```
public ActionResult DeleteOldLogs()
{
    var oldDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-14);
    var oldItems = context.Loggs.Where(u => u.LoggDate < oldDate);
    context.Loggs.RemoveRange(oldItems);
    context.SaveChanges();

    return Content("Deleted successfully");
}
```

When this code gets executed, EF will issue one `SELECT` query to get the older records and execute `N` number of `DELETE` queries where `N` is the number records returned from the first SELECT query.

Another option is to call Remove for each item in your oldItems collection

```
var oldItems = context.Loggs.Where(u => u.LoggDate < oldDate);
foreach (var oldItem in oldItems)
{
    context.Loggs.Remove(oldItem);
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

Keep in mind that you are calling the `AddDays` methods to the current time stamp. So if your table column has time stamp(`DateTime`), it will delete the records after that timestamp(*not from 12.00 AM*)

Answer (score 1):

```
public ActionResult DeleteOldLogs()
{
  var datesToRemove = OldDates();
  using (context)
  { 
    foreach (var item in datesToRemove)
    {
        context.Loggs.Remove(item);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
  }
}
```