# Get EF Core generated query including parameters

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I need the SQL generated for a query.

Since EF Core 5, we have `IQueryable.ToQueryString()` which provides the query itself without parameters.

The best I could find [is this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16625307/9971404), which extracts parameters from the query using reflection. It works for all database providers. However it is for pre-Core EF.

How can I get the query AND parameters - either in the query itself, or as an array of objects like in the linked question? (Using reflection is ok, unless there's a better way.)

Comment: In case it's important, I'm using both the sqlite ad posgtres providers. But I'm hoping for a db-independent solution.

Comment: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/simple-logging

Comment: the doco for ef is top notch

Comment: @Jazb Thanks. I actually did try that, but the parameters are logged separately - so it's not useful during runtime. You can actually see an example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/simple-logging#message-contents-and-formatting), if there are parameters they are included the bit that says `Parameters=[...]`. Also, this is useful for diagnostics "after the fact", but what I'm after is to determine the query (e.g. `ToQueryString()`) during runtime.

Comment: What are you trying to implement? Executing queries via remote server?

Comment: It's complicated :) for our internal tools. I want the query and the parameters, and to put them into `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(query, parameters)` like in that linked question.

Comment: EFC 6.0 `ToQueryString()` includes the parameters and their values before the SQL text (using the db provider syntax, for instance `DECLARE @{param_name} = {param_value}` SqlServer statements). You can browse the `ToQueryString` implementation in their GitHub repository and see how they do it. If you need it just for execution, EFC 6.0 `ToQueryString()` is ready for (non parameterized) execution. But note that it can't be used for split queries. So, it is complicated :)

Comment: Well, if you need `Delete` or other stuff, just use this extension [inq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore)