# Efficient way to delete multiple rows with Linq to Entity?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

Hi I'm looking for efficient way to delete multiple records at once. I'm deleting 400 records and it takes 8-15 seconds. Here is my code

```
using (var entities = new Entity())
   {                               
       foreach (Item item in entities.Items.Where(x => x.id == id))
              entities.DeleteObject(item);
       entities.SaveChanges();
   }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bulk-deleting in LINQ to Entities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869209/bulk-deleting-in-linq-to-entities)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it faster using [EntityFramework.Extensions](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended)
1) First install EntityFramework.Extensions using NuGet

2) Here is the code similar to Linq2Sql's DeleteAllOnSubmit():

```
using EntityFramework.Extensions;
```

....

```
using (var entities = new Entity())
{                               
    entities.Items.Delete(x => x.id == id);
    entities.SaveChanges();
}

...
```

Comment: It requires package `EntityFramework.Extended` https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Bulk-deleting in LINQ to Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869209/bulk-deleting-in-linq-to-entities/870081#870081) or [PLINQO for Entity Framework](http://www.codesmithtools.com/product/frameworks#plinqoef) if it's the sort of delete you could do in a single batch, i.e.

```
DELETE FROM Entities WHERE [some condition]
```

Otherwise, maybe check you've got an index on the `x` column you're using to find each record.

Comment: query.Delete(); What logic Do I need to implement in Delete method? foreach loop and do the same ? How it will different?

Answer (score 0):

In your loop:

```
using (var entities = new Entity()) 
{                                
    foreach (Item item in entities.Items.Where(x => x.id == id)) 
           entities.DeleteObject(item); 
    entities.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

If you move the entities.SaveChanges(); so that it runs after the loop, it will run substantially faster.

```
using (var entities = new Entity()) 
{                                
    foreach (Item item in entities.Items.Where(x => x.id == id)) 
          entities.DeleteObject(item); 
} 
entities.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: -1: This code stub makes no sense, since the call to SaveChanges is placed outside the using scope where the entities variable does not exist.

Comment: Actually, this makes perfect sense.  Correct that he mis-typed on accident, but this is the most correct answer from what I can tell.  Just have to edit it a little, which I'll do now.