# Using metadata to delete all entities in an object graph

Tags: breeze

This is a bit of a general question.

If I mark an entity as setDeleted, is it possible to get Breeze to also mark children / grandchildren etc. entities in the entire object graph for deletion before saveChanges is called?

Alternatively, if I'm doing soft-deletes by placing a boolean property isDeleted on all entities and setting it to true if an entity is soft-deleted, is it possible to get Breeze to change this property for a parent entity and all children / grandchildren etc. when the entity is marked for setModified and before the entities are saved?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose has already been answered [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221693/error-with-breeze-when-deleting-an-entity-which-contains-child-entities).

Cascade delete on client is not supported by breeze as of now.

Comment: I am experiencing inconsistent behaviour in Breeze with this. Please see [***this question***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21679073/entity-framework-object-graph-deletion-with-breeze) wherein I provide a more specific example where breezejs is cascading a delete in one case and not in another. This question was intended as a more general one.